# JQM nested list in custom select menu

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am creating a mobile application using jQuery Mobile and on one of the pages I have a form which requires chained selects (3 of them).

I was thinking that instead of having 3 separate selects I could have 1 custom select that opens a nested list.

Can this be achieved using the custom select menus ( as I see it already creates a list for you if there are many options), or would I have to create my own nested list and open it in a popup?